# Why do I have InputMismatchException when reading a text file with multiple lines?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("members.txt.txt"));
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) 
            {
                scan.useDelimiter(",");
                String name = scan.next();
                int admin = scan.nextInt();
                int analyst = scan.nextInt();
                int creative = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println("I am here");
                int finisher = scan.nextInt();

                System.out.println("name: "+name+"admin "+admin+"analyst "+analyst+"creative "+creative+"finisher "+finisher);                  
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I use this to read from text file. The text file itself:

```
Mona,2,10,8,10
Morten,5,5,15,5
Lisa,12,8,2,8
Vanessa,20,5,1,4
Yoana,10,10,5,5
Krassimira,20,1,1,8
Baltmore,3,0,0,0
COca,4,1,5,20
Pasi,5,5,5,15
```

It throws an exception and I have no idea why, but when the file looks like this:

```
Mona,2,5,18,5Peter,10,8,0,12Jacob,2,5,18,3nikos
```

I mean with one big line the code works fine. I really would appreciate a good answer and the fact that if you notice for example *,5Peter* in some parts
the number of finisher is glued with a name and the code works that way drives me crazy.

Comment: Mona,2,10,8,10
Morten,5,5,15,5
Lisa,12,8,2,8
Vanessa,20,5,1,4
Yoana,10,10,5,5
Krassimira,20,1,1,8
Baltmore,3,0,0,0


COca,4,1,5,20

Pasi,5,5,5,15

Comment: The first time the code is on multiple lines the second is line big line.

Comment: Are lines in your text file space delimited or new-line delimited? From your post, it appears like each line is space-delimited.

Comment: The delimiter you're using is ",", but your file also contains the line separator as a delimiter. And why does your file change its content? Your just reading it. So you should add the code that writes/changes the file to the question.

Comment: public void writeToFile()
    {
        FileWriter output;
        try
        {
            output = new FileWriter(new File(fileMembers));
            for (int i = 0; i < memlist.size(); i++) 
            {
               Member member = memlist.get(i);
               output.write(member.toFile());                
            }
            output.close();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: this the function and this is the func in Member class that writes to the file

Comment: public String toFile()
{
    return name+","+admin+","+analyst+","+creative+","+finisher+"\n";
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mona,2,5,18,5Peter
```

The fifth element you scan `5Peter` is supposed to be `int`:

```
int finisher = scan.nextInt();
```

but it gets a `String`. Probably that is the issue. It looks like there is a comma missing between `5` and `Peter` so it pulls 2 elements as one and tries to treat them as `int` but gets a `String` because of the missing comma.

Comment: no the code works fine with the second file when is one big continues line, the code doesnt work with the first file when all the people are on separete lines.

Comment: @GukammmmSiiiiiii If you put a comma at the end of the line it will probably work. If you can do that.

Comment: Mona,2,5,18,5Peter,10,8,0,12Jacob,2,5,18,3nikos

Comment: A comma on every line except the last one.

Comment: any ideas why this work despite the fact there is no comma between 5 and Peter

Comment: Putting it all on one line, but without a comma between 5 and Peter, does not work for me.  I cannot duplicate your success when all the data is on a single line, but missing delimiting commas.

Comment: When write to the file I write every object with this toFile function

Comment: public String toFile()
    {
         return name+","+admin+","+analyst+","+creative+","+finisher+"\n";
    }

Comment: but still in the file looks like one big connected line.

Comment: @GukammmmSiiiiiii because you're using windows and it uses "\r\n" instead of a single "\n".

Answer (score 2):

You have defined the delimiter as ",". Since there's no "," between lines, the scanner treats the last word and the first word of the next line as the same word.